# Play sound on receive VoIP notification when device is in silent mode in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, notifications, voip

I want to implement the functionality where user receive VoIP notification and user device is in silent mode and than also music will play.Can any one help me in this ? I searched about this question but not getting exact idea.please help.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? What's not working? What error messages are you getting? etc. Please check out these helpful docs - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - to learn how to best ask a question on SO.